# Get Process ID of the current running build on Azure DevOps

Tags: python, windows, azure-devops, codeql

I'm trying to piece together some scripts to add CodeQL scanning to a existing build pipeline on Azure DevOps.
For compiled languages such as .NET, a pre-compile command is required to create a CodeQL database to watch the compile. I have set this up as follows:

YAML:

```
parameters:
  - name: githubToken
    default: ''
  - name: buildType
    default: ''
  - name: codeql_db
    default: "codeql-db"

steps:
- script: |
    echo "##vso[task.prependpath]/apps/ado/tools/codeql"
  displayName: 'Setup codeql'
- task: PythonScript@0
  displayName: 'CodeQL setup environment'
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'filepath'
    scriptPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/utils/codeql_setup.py'
    arguments: '--github-token ${{ parameters.githubToken }} --build-type ${{ parameters.buildType }} --repository-name $(Build.Repository.Name) --repository-path $(Build.Repository.LocalPath) --agent-os $(agent.os) --codeql-db ${{ parameters.codeql_db }}'
    workingDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)
```

codeql_setup.py:

```
if build_type in compiled_buildtypes:
    print('Compiled build type identified. Setting up indirect build tracing.', flush=True)
    codeql_setup_command = ['codeql', 'database', 'init','--source-root', repository_local_path, '--language', repo_languages_argument, '--begin-tracing', codeql_db_name, '--overwrite']
    
    # Set additional options
    if len(repo_languages) > 1 :
        print('Multiple languages detected.', flush=True)
        codeql_setup_command.append('--db-cluster')
    if 'windows' in agent_os.lower():
        print('Windows Agent detected.', flush=True)
        codeql_setup_command.append(f'--trace-process-level {PROCESS_NUMBER}')

    database_init_proc = subprocess.run(codeql_setup_command, env=os.environ.copy())
    print('CodeQL database setup for indirect build tracing.', flush=True)
```

My issue is the second additional argument. [For Windows agents, the process number or parent process name is required for codeQL to watch the compile](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/codeql-cli/getting-started-with-the-codeql-cli/preparing-your-code-for-codeql-analysis#using-indirect-build-tracing).

Is there a simple way to get the process ID of the build? Similar to how I have retrieved the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked the CodeQL scanning code and the Github doc. You need to get the current **Agent.Worker.exe** process id.

To meet your requirement, you can use the following PowerShell command to get the Process ID.

```
Get-Process Agent.Worker  | Select id
```

And then you can set the ProcessID as Pipeline variable.

For example:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   Get-Process Agent.Worker  | Select id
   
   $test = Get-Process Agent.Worker  | Select id
   
   echo $test.id
   
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ProcessID]$test.id"
```

You can use the variable: `$(ProcessID)` in the next tasks.